# YA book where the male protagonist has a father missing who was caught up in a war between humans and robots

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, robots

I'm trying to find a YA book from the 2010s with robots.

It had a male protagonist with a missing father who was caught up in a war between humans and robots. I think a friendly robot was smuggled into the city he lived in and wore human clothes to disguise himself. This character might have been called Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this be *[Bot Wars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13294266-bot-wars)* (2013) by J.V. Kade, the first book in the *Bot Wars* duology...?

The Goodreads summary mentions a male protagonist, a missing father, and a war between robots and humans:

> **Twelve-year-old Trout St. Kroix has been searching for his missing father for the last two years, after his dad disappeared while fighting in the Bot Wars. The Bot Wars began after robots became so advanced that they revolted and demanded more workers' rights, causing the government to declare all robots terrorists and ban them from the Districts.** Trout never questioned anything the government told him--even when his own nanny bot was banished--until a vid he posts about his missing dad goes viral and new information pops up. At first Trout is wrenched his dad might be alive, but when his brother disappears, Trout learns nothing is what it seems . . . not even his own father.
>
> Percy Jackson meets Transformers in this heart-stopping, futuristic adventure that will make you question everything you know--and look at robots in a whole new light.

And [this review](https://guitarheroart.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/bot-wars-by-j-v-kade-book-review-school-book-report/) mentions a robot named LT, who apparently helps the protagonist, Trout:

> Trout’s father has been found, and he’s in bot territory. The UD is chasing after Trout, and Po has been captured and the evil, corrupt UD is trying to find their dad, because they no something no one does, Trout’s dad is the leader of the bot supporting group The Meta-Rise, a group that is against the UD and go to illegal ways to stop the UD. But the UD is evil so that’s a good thing. **A bot named LT rescues Trout, and they flee through a version of the underground railroad.**

Comment: Yes. This is it.